# URL checker is very slow

Tags: php, url

I have +-645 IRL links I need to validate. The code below is my attempt, but my problem is that it takes forever to check all links and sometimes times out. Is there a better way of validating so many links?

**index.php**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$notValid = [];

// This array contains +-645 url in this array, http://www.example.com is just for example purposes.
$companyData = ['http://www.example.com','http://www.example.com', 'http://www.example.com', 'http://www.example.com'];
// Basic structure of $companyData array

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Name-Ltd
            [Code] => XYZ
            [Url] => http://www.example.co.za/example-click-a-company/Name-Ltd
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [[Name] => Name-Ltd
            [Code] => ZXY
            [Url] => http://www.example.co.za/example-click-a-company/Name-Ltd
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Name-Ltd
            [Code] => ZYX
            [Url] => http://www.example.co.za/example-click-a-company/Name-Ltd
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Name-Ltd
            [Code] => YZX
            [Url] => http://www.example.co.za/example-click-a-company/Name-Ltd
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Name-Ltd
            [Code] => XZY
            [Url] => http://www.example.co.za/example-click-a-company/Name-Ltd

)

// This is to loop through all url's
for ($i=0; $i < count($companyData); $i++) 
{ 
    $url = $companyData[$i]['Url'];

    $headers = get_headers($url, 1);

    if(@$headers['Content-Length'] == 1153) 
    {
        $exists = 'not valid';

        $notValid[$i] = $companyData[$i]['Url'];
    }
    else 
    {
        $exists = 'valid';
    }
}

foreach ($notValid as $not) 
{
    echo "The following URL's need your attention: <br>";
    echo $not;
}

?>
```

Comment: you make a request for each url every-time you want to verify? no wonder it is slow, cache the result

Comment: @ratchetfreak hi, do you know of any website or link i can go lookup on caching

Comment: @WayneLinks caching is no magic. Just save the output from get_headers into a file or database so you dont have to do a request the second time you validate this url. If this makes sense depends on how often you validate the same url

Comment: @WayneLinks: How up-to-date do you need this information to be? Wouldn't it be better for you to have a cron running once or twice a day, that checks these urls? Store/cache that data somewhere, notify the admin (you, sys admin, whoever is supposed to be notified) by sending a mail, a push message, an AMQP message, smoke signals,  whatever... PS: `@$headers` -> just use `isset`, and not the `@` operator of death

Comment: @braunbaer I hear what you say, it does seem as if the initial run to check the url's the first time might take long, after that with the practice of caching then it will go faster. My main problem is the initial attemp that takes long, is there not a way i can set time interval so not to overwhelm the sever.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem That is the idea yes,

Comment: I was thinking maybe i should use set_time_limit(3600) just to avoid it timing out on me.With the first run ofcourse

Comment: @WayneLinks not sure which server you are talking about. Just to clearify. Your script is making a HTTP REQUEST for every URL. There is not much you can do as most of the time you are just waiting for the RESPONSE of servers. The "natural" thing to do would be to parallelize your script so you can do multiple requests. Keep in mind: parallelization with php is not an easy task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is slow because you are doing a sequence of HTTP REQUESTS. Most of the time your server / script is just waiting for the RESPONSE of the requested URL.

#### small things you can do

- as mentioned yourself in the comments you can change your max execution time to prevent reaching it. (which does not make your script any faster ; -)
- move away from get headers and use curl or similar to have the ability to change the connection timeout. You could set it to 1 sec and flag every url which fails to manual review (assuming all healthy urls will respond in time , and some slow false positives). Small benefit: your script should be finished in max url*sec time

#### big things

so the problem is: in practice is your script waiting for responses, in theory it does not have to , as the checking of an url does not depend on each other. Classic case for parallelization. Downside: php is not the language you want to do parallelization in.

upside: you are not the first with this problem

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308779/php-parallel-curl-requests
- http://reactphp.org/

or use golang or something with build in parallelization

Comment: Thanks for the links, definitely made me think about my script. This will definitely help.

Comment: Though it's hardly easier than multiple curl requests, OP _could_ use non-blocking socket streams. If only because it allows for a bit more debugging options in case an url goes down, and because getting to grips with sockets is helpful if you're looking into other (more low-level) languages